# Alter python default behavior (-u) when distributing tools

Tags: python, command-line-interface, pyinstaller

I have a set of python 2.7 tools that is best run using the -u flag (unbuffered binary stdout and stderr) when run from the command line.

`python -u myscript.py`

Is there a way to force the -u flag to be the default when i distribute my program? Note that I am not looking to add a argument through argparse, but rather would have the -u flag mean, turn OFF the flush flag. Is this possible, is there a reason (compatibility?) why this might be a bad idea?

Comment: Linux or Windows?

Comment: dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/disable-output-buffering

Comment: Agreed. Duplicated from here. Accepted.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/disable-output-buffering